# Admob onAdWillDismissFullScreenContent is not working

Tags: flutter, admob

I have an application that I use Admob. Although it works well in the simulator, it does not work properly on phones. After the ad ends, it does not go to another page when it should go.

```
void _loadInterstitialAd() {
InterstitialAd.load(
  adUnitId: AdHelper.interstitialAdUnitId,
  request: AdRequest(),
  adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
    onAdLoaded: (ad) {
      ad.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
        onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (ad, a) {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => MakeTheSameShapeScorePage(
                        score: score,
                      )));
        },
        onAdWillDismissFullScreenContent: (ad) {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => MakeTheSameShapeScorePage(
                        score: score,
                      )));
        },
```